# How to find Kendo UI dependency on jQuery

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

How do i find which jQuery version is required/supported for a particular Kendo UI library?

For example i installed Telerik's UI for ASP.NET MVC 5 version 2016.3.1118. This libarary uses Kendo UI for client side. I wanted to know can i use latest version of jQuery 3.3.7 along with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is listed at: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites

From this it lists the most recent version of Kendo UI using Jquery version: 1.12.3, but that this is also compatible with 1.10.x, 2.2.x and 3.1.1.

So, you may want to only use Jquery version 3.1.1 for this latest version of Kendo UI.

Comment: The Telerik KEndo-UI pre-requisites link was changed to https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/jquery-support. The JQuery supported is 1.12.4 , also compatible with 1.10.x, 2.2.x and 3.6.0